# TextInputEditText requestFocus in XML causes rendering problems

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-support-library, android-textinputlayout

It seems like I can't put `requestFocus` inside my `TextInputEditText` since it causes rendering problems on the preview screen with this stack trace:

```
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Unable to find resource ID #0x1ff0005
at android.content.res.Resources.getResourceName(Resources.java:2235)
at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:2602)
at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2540)
at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:806)
at android.content.Context.getDrawable(Context.java:458)
at android.widget.Editor.updateCursorPosition(Editor.java:2007)
at android.widget.Editor.updateCursorsPositions(Editor.java:1703)
at android.widget.TextView.getUpdatedHighlightPath(TextView.java:5526)
at android.widget.TextView.onDraw(TextView.java:5713)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:16178)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:16090)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild_Original(ViewGroup.java:3609)
at android.view.ViewGroup_Delegate.drawChild(ViewGroup_Delegate.java:61)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3609)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3399)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:16181)
at android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout.draw(TextInputLayout.java:845)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:16090)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild_Original(ViewGroup.java:3609)
at android.view.ViewGroup_Delegate.drawChild(ViewGroup_Delegate.java:61)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3609)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3399)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:16088)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild_Original(ViewGroup.java:3609)
at android.view.ViewGroup_Delegate.drawChild(ViewGroup_Delegate.java:61)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3609)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3399)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:16088)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild_Original(ViewGroup.java:3609)
at android.view.ViewGroup_Delegate.drawChild(ViewGroup_Delegate.java:61)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3609)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3399)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:16088)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild_Original(ViewGroup.java:3609)
at android.view.ViewGroup_Delegate.drawChild(ViewGroup_Delegate.java:61)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3609)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3399)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:16088)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild_Original(ViewGroup.java:3609)
at android.view.ViewGroup_Delegate.drawChild(ViewGroup_Delegate.java:61)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3609)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3399)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:16181)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.render(RenderSessionImpl.java:431)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:428)
at com.android.ide.common.rendering.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:350)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$2.compute(RenderTask.java:510)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$2.compute(RenderTask.java:498)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:888)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.createRenderSession(RenderTask.java:498)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.access$600(RenderTask.java:72)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$3.call(RenderTask.java:610)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$3.call(RenderTask.java:607)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderService.runRenderAction(RenderService.java:362)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.render(RenderTask.java:607)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.render(RenderTask.java:629)
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.doRender(AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.java:652)
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.access$1700(AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.java:80)
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager$7$1.run(AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.java:594)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$2.run(CoreProgressManager.java:152)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:452)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:402)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:54)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:137)
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager$7.run(AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.java:589)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.execute(MergingUpdateQueue.java:320)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.execute(MergingUpdateQueue.java:310)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue$2.run(MergingUpdateQueue.java:254)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.flush(MergingUpdateQueue.java:269)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.flush(MergingUpdateQueue.java:227)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.run(MergingUpdateQueue.java:217)
at com.intellij.util.concurrency.QueueProcessor.runSafely(QueueProcessor.java:238)
at com.intellij.util.Alarm$Request$1.run(Alarm.java:351)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

**XML**

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
    ... >

    <requestFocus />
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText>
```

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Stacktrace is saying **android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Unable to find resource ID #0x1ff0005**. Are you sure the resource is present in the xml or you are referring correct id?

Comment: @BaluSKT I don't think it's a problem on my side, Sir. I did not refer any resource id in my XML, the error showed up _only_ when I include `<requestFocus />`

Answer (score 5):

The following Java code works for me:

```
TextInputEditText tEdit = ( TextInputEditText ) findViewById(...);
tEdit.requestFocus(); // (java)

<requestFocus() /> //not work for TextinputEditText in xml.
```

Answer (score 1):

Just wrap the `TextInputEditText` with a `TextInputLayout` and add the     `<requestFocus />` tag to the `TextInputLayout` instead, that should do the trick.

So your XML will look something like this -

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:imeOptions="actionDone"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

   <requestFocus />
</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```